# How can I adjust sound on a youtube video [selenium Python]

Tags: python, selenium, video, automation

the below is an example of controlling the play button. but how do i control the volume bar? my usual methods dont work.

this is what i have now. my usual methods of trying to hit the element is not working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Max/Desktop/Code/Selenium/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXUAyRRkI6k')

for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
player = driver.find_element_by_id('movie_player')
player.send_keys(Keys.SPACE) 
time.sleep(1)
player.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** For volume up/down, you can try `ARROW_UP` and `ARROW_DOWN`:

```
player.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
```

**(2)** For volume un-mute, you can try `send_keys("m")`:

```
player.send_keys("m")
```

**PS:** Code below is untested but you could try it for clicking the volume icon.
 The icon is called `Mute (m)` but I don't know if it will respond to a Selenium `click()` command...

```
testbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Mute (m)']")
testbtn.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `ActionChains()`:

```
sound_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ytp-mute-button')
volume_panel = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ytp-volume-panel')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(sound_button)
actions.move_to_element(volume_panel)
actions.click_and_hold(volume_panel)
actions.move_to_element_with_offset(volume_panel, 20, 0)
actions.perform()
```

This sound bar can be moved from -20 to 20 using this line:

```
actions.move_to_element_with_offset(volume_panel, 20, 0)
```

So, for max volume it will be `(volume_panel, 20, 0)`, for min volume it will be `(volume_panel, -20, 0)` and you can set any volume between -20 and 20